# Why the transition is disabled?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

So, I was trying to apply Wipe transition to an image but it was disabled like in the picture. Is there something I'm doing wrong? [image]

Comment: Are your clips overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two overlapping strips to be able to add a Wipe transition.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying this while selecting only one clip. Turns out, I have to select both of them and then apply the transition.